# Trend Analysis in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to analyze trends over few weeks of data.
For the sake of simplicity, 2 columns Date, Value
I want to get the deviation of yesterday's value over same weekday going back for few weeks.

pseudo code:

select date, deviation(value) over average(value) where date = previous Monday
from table
where date > sysdate - 35

How to do this in SQL?

Sorry for the silly question

Comment: Can you share your best SQL coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: Can you post sample tables, sample data, expected results, and the calculations that you want to make?  I can guess but some of your pseudocode is ambiguous.  For example, is "deviation(value)" defined as "value - average(value)"?  The absolute value of that expression?  Or something else?  Is "average(value)" the average for the full data set?  The average as of that date?  Or something else (i.e. a moving average)?  Is the "where" clause just limiting the rows that are displayed or does it limit the rows that are considered in the calculations?

Answer (score 0):

The question without some sample data and expected result is always confusing. It would be good if you could provide it. Meanwhile, I'll try to offer something.
**1. Sample data generation using WITH clause:**

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (   
            Select  
                SYSDATE - LEVEL - 1 "A_DATE", 
                Round(dbms_random.value*100*LEVEL/7, 2) "A_VALUE"
            From    
                Dual    
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 96  
        ),
--
--  Sample Data
--
--  A_DATE       A_VALUE
--  --------- ----------
--  05-AUG-22       6.82 
--  04-AUG-22      14.76 
--  03-AUG-22      23.95 
--  02-AUG-22      23.37 
--  01-AUG-22       64.4 
--  31-JUL-22      64.89 
--  30-JUL-22      66.52 
--  29-JUL-22      51.88 
--  28-JUL-22      69.72 
--  27-JUL-22     113.55
--  ........    ........
--  ........    ........
```

As I managed to understand you are asking for some weekly statistics and/or comparisons. If that is the case then there should be one more cte created to define week numbers, week days and (for future comparison) define the week before.
**2. Create weeks cte**

```sql
    weeks AS
        (
            Select
                A_DATE "A_DATE",
                To_Char(A_DATE, 'D') "DAY_NR", 
                To_Char(A_DATE, 'DAY') "DAY_NAME",
                A_VALUE "A_VALUE",
                To_Number(To_Char(A_DATE, 'iw')) "WEEK_NR",
                To_Number(To_Char(A_DATE, 'iw')) -1  "WEEK_NR_BEFORE"
            From    
                tbl 
            Order By 
                A_DATE
        )  
--
--  weeks cte data
--
--  A_DATE    DAY_NR DAY_NAME     A_VALUE    WEEK_NR WEEK_NR_BEFORE
--  --------- ------ --------- ---------- ---------- --------------
--  05-AUG-22 5      FRIDAY          11.7         31             30 
--  04-AUG-22 4      THURSDAY         .28         31             30 
--  03-AUG-22 3      WEDNESDAY       8.77         31             30 
--  02-AUG-22 2      TUESDAY           38         31             30 
--  01-AUG-22 1      MONDAY         25.13         31             30 
--  31-JUL-22 7      SUNDAY          3.18         30             29 
--  30-JUL-22 6      SATURDAY       18.25         30             29 
--  29-JUL-22 5      FRIDAY         32.71         30             29 
--  28-JUL-22 4      THURSDAY        9.16         30             29 
--  27-JUL-22 3      WEDNESDAY      36.43         30             29 
--  26-JUL-22 2      TUESDAY         3.57         30             29 
--  25-JUL-22 1      MONDAY         79.26         30             29 
--  24-JUL-22 7      SUNDAY        123.75         29             28 
--  23-JUL-22 6      SATURDAY      192.91         29             28 
--  22-JUL-22 5      FRIDAY        204.01         29             28 
--  21-JUL-22 4      THURSDAY       34.13         29             28 
--  20-JUL-22 3      WEDNESDAY     190.26         29             28 
--  19-JUL-22 2      TUESDAY       159.21         29             28 
--  18-JUL-22 1      MONDAY        113.85         29             28 
--  ..........      .........    ........       ....            ...
--  ..........      .........    ........       ....            ...
```

This cte contains more or less everything that is needed to get out some aggregations, analysys and statistics based on weekly data. Below is the main SQL to get you some of the data.
**3. Main SQL**

```sql
Select
    w.A_DATE "A_DATE",
    w.DAY_NR "DAY_NR",
    w.DAY_NAME "DAY_NAME",
    w.A_VALUE "A_VALUE",
    w.WEEK_NR "WEEK_NR",
    Sum(w.A_VALUE) OVER(PARTITION BY w.WEEK_NR ORDER BY w.WEEK_NR) "WEEK_SUM",
    Min(w.A_VALUE) OVER(PARTITION BY w.WEEK_NR ORDER BY w.WEEK_NR) "WEEK_MIN",
    Max(w.A_VALUE) OVER(PARTITION BY w.WEEK_NR ORDER BY w.WEEK_NR) "WEEK_MAX",
    Round(Avg(w.A_VALUE) OVER(PARTITION BY w.WEEK_NR ORDER BY w.WEEK_NR), 6) "WEEK_AVG",
    Round(STDDEV(w.A_VALUE) OVER(PARTITION BY w.WEEK_NR ORDER BY w.WEEK_NR), 6) "WEEK_DEV",
    --
    --  D a t a   F r o m   W e e k   B e f o r e
    ( Select wb.A_DATE From weeks wb Where wb.WEEK_NR = w.WEEK_NR_BEFORE And wb.A_DATE = w.A_DATE - 7   ) "A_DATE_BEFORE",
    ( Select wb.A_VALUE From weeks wb Where wb.WEEK_NR = w.WEEK_NR_BEFORE And wb.A_DATE = w.A_DATE - 7   ) "A_VALUE_BEFORE",
    w.WEEK_NR_BEFORE "WEEK_NR_BEFORE",
    ( Select Sum(wb.A_VALUE) From weeks wb Where wb.WEEK_NR = w.WEEK_NR_BEFORE Group By wb.WEEK_NR  ) "WEEK_BEFORE_SUM",
    ( Select Min(wb.A_VALUE) From weeks wb Where wb.WEEK_NR = w.WEEK_NR_BEFORE Group By wb.WEEK_NR  ) "WEEK_BEFORE_MIN",
    ( Select Max(wb.A_VALUE) From weeks wb Where wb.WEEK_NR = w.WEEK_NR_BEFORE Group By wb.WEEK_NR  ) "WEEK_BEFORE_MAX",
    Round(( Select Avg(wb.A_VALUE) From weeks wb Where wb.WEEK_NR = w.WEEK_NR_BEFORE Group By wb.WEEK_NR  ), 6) "WEEK_BEFORE_AVG",
    Round(( Select STDDEV(wb.A_VALUE) From weeks wb Where wb.WEEK_NR = w.WEEK_NR_BEFORE Group By wb.WEEK_NR  ), 6) "WEEK_BEFORE_DEV"
From
    weeks w
Where
    WEEK_NR >= To_Number(To_Char(SYSDATE-1, 'iw')) - 3  -- Data from three last weeks
--
--  R e s u l t   -  for last 3 weeks   -
--
--  A_DATE    DAY_NR DAY_NAME     A_VALUE    WEEK_NR   WEEK_SUM   WEEK_MIN   WEEK_MAX   WEEK_AVG   WEEK_DEV A_DATE_BEFORE A_VALUE_BEFORE WEEK_NR_BEFORE WEEK_BEFORE_SUM WEEK_BEFORE_MIN WEEK_BEFORE_MAX WEEK_BEFORE_AVG WEEK_BEFORE_DEV
--  --------- ------ --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------- -------------- -------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
--  15-JUL-22 5      FRIDAY        119.96         28    1161.07      65.03     249.51 165.867143  75.922132 08-JUL-22             304.61             27         1760.53           69.47          429.25      251.504286      136.732372 
--  14-JUL-22 4      THURSDAY       83.26         28    1161.07      65.03     249.51 165.867143  75.922132 07-JUL-22              75.72             27         1760.53           69.47          429.25      251.504286      136.732372 
--  13-JUL-22 3      WEDNESDAY      65.03         28    1161.07      65.03     249.51 165.867143  75.922132 06-JUL-22             336.45             27         1760.53           69.47          429.25      251.504286      136.732372 
--  12-JUL-22 2      TUESDAY       204.96         28    1161.07      65.03     249.51 165.867143  75.922132 05-JUL-22              69.47             27         1760.53           69.47          429.25      251.504286      136.732372 
--  11-JUL-22 1      MONDAY        249.51         28    1161.07      65.03     249.51 165.867143  75.922132 04-JUL-22             429.25             27         1760.53           69.47          429.25      251.504286      136.732372 
--  16-JUL-22 6      SATURDAY      244.45         28    1161.07      65.03     249.51 165.867143  75.922132 09-JUL-22             219.48             27         1760.53           69.47          429.25      251.504286      136.732372 
--  17-JUL-22 7      SUNDAY         193.9         28    1161.07      65.03     249.51 165.867143  75.922132 10-JUL-22             325.55             27         1760.53           69.47          429.25      251.504286      136.732372 
--  22-JUL-22 5      FRIDAY         36.97         29     781.87       4.34     206.14 111.695714  77.563311 15-JUL-22             119.96             28         1161.07           65.03          249.51      165.867143       75.922132 
--  21-JUL-22 4      THURSDAY       62.73         29     781.87       4.34     206.14 111.695714  77.563311 14-JUL-22              83.26             28         1161.07           65.03          249.51      165.867143       75.922132 
--  20-JUL-22 3      WEDNESDAY       4.34         29     781.87       4.34     206.14 111.695714  77.563311 13-JUL-22              65.03             28         1161.07           65.03          249.51      165.867143       75.922132 
--  19-JUL-22 2      TUESDAY       132.36         29     781.87       4.34     206.14 111.695714  77.563311 12-JUL-22             204.96             28         1161.07           65.03          249.51      165.867143       75.922132 
--  18-JUL-22 1      MONDAY        206.14         29     781.87       4.34     206.14 111.695714  77.563311 11-JUL-22             249.51             28         1161.07           65.03          249.51      165.867143       75.922132 
--  23-JUL-22 6      SATURDAY      185.82         29     781.87       4.34     206.14 111.695714  77.563311 16-JUL-22             244.45             28         1161.07           65.03          249.51      165.867143       75.922132 
--  24-JUL-22 7      SUNDAY        153.51         29     781.87       4.34     206.14 111.695714  77.563311 17-JUL-22              193.9             28         1161.07           65.03          249.51      165.867143       75.922132 
--  25-JUL-22 1      MONDAY         68.21         30      405.1        2.5     142.13  57.871429  44.487517 18-JUL-22             206.14             29          781.87            4.34          206.14      111.695714       77.563311 
--  26-JUL-22 2      TUESDAY        54.58         30      405.1        2.5     142.13  57.871429  44.487517 19-JUL-22             132.36             29          781.87            4.34          206.14      111.695714       77.563311 
--  27-JUL-22 3      WEDNESDAY     142.13         30      405.1        2.5     142.13  57.871429  44.487517 20-JUL-22               4.34             29          781.87            4.34          206.14      111.695714       77.563311 
--  28-JUL-22 4      THURSDAY       42.84         30      405.1        2.5     142.13  57.871429  44.487517 21-JUL-22              62.73             29          781.87            4.34          206.14      111.695714       77.563311 
--  29-JUL-22 5      FRIDAY           2.5         30      405.1        2.5     142.13  57.871429  44.487517 22-JUL-22              36.97             29          781.87            4.34          206.14      111.695714       77.563311 
--  30-JUL-22 6      SATURDAY       23.47         30      405.1        2.5     142.13  57.871429  44.487517 23-JUL-22             185.82             29          781.87            4.34          206.14      111.695714       77.563311 
--  31-JUL-22 7      SUNDAY         71.37         30      405.1        2.5     142.13  57.871429  44.487517 24-JUL-22             153.51             29          781.87            4.34          206.14      111.695714       77.563311 
--  01-AUG-22 1      MONDAY         69.44         31     145.87          1      69.44     29.174  26.597711 25-JUL-22              68.21             30           405.1             2.5          142.13       57.871429       44.487517 
--  02-AUG-22 2      TUESDAY        24.69         31     145.87          1      69.44     29.174  26.597711 26-JUL-22              54.58             30           405.1             2.5          142.13       57.871429       44.487517 
--  03-AUG-22 3      WEDNESDAY      38.89         31     145.87          1      69.44     29.174  26.597711 27-JUL-22             142.13             30           405.1             2.5          142.13       57.871429       44.487517 
--  04-AUG-22 4      THURSDAY       11.85         31     145.87          1      69.44     29.174  26.597711 28-JUL-22              42.84             30           405.1             2.5          142.13       57.871429       44.487517 
--  05-AUG-22 5      FRIDAY             1         31     145.87          1      69.44     29.174  26.597711 29-JUL-22                2.5             30           405.1             2.5          142.13       57.871429       44.487517
```

Result containes the data from actual week in the same row with the data from week before. There are Sum, Min, Max, Avg, StdDev values for both weeks. This can be changed any way you want using a combination of data preparing cte (weeks in this case) plus different analytic functions (...OVER() ) and group aggregations. The resulting dataset can be processed further more if needed or structured in a different way, but for that you should review and clarify the question. Maybe this could be helpfull to you to find your own solution. For anyhing more specific please provide a few rows of your sample data with the expected outcome. Regards...

P.S.
**Important note: the resulting values in particular parts of the answer are not the same because the sample data generation depends on dbms.random.value so the data are different every time the SQL is executed.**